# Use Java Language Server outside Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, compiler-warnings

I joined a new team, we develop a Spring Boot application.

When I open the project with Visual Studio Code, I get almost 1,000 warnings, errors and infos under the *Problems* tab within Visual Studio Code.

These problems are reported by the [Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java).

It appears my colleagues use IntelliJ Idea and do not see these problems.

What I want to do is the following:

- Provide an equivalent level of Java language support for IntelliJ Idea (Ultimate) users.
- Set the Java compiler options to an equivalent level, so that our CI/CD server rejects smelly code.

Is there a simple way to integrate the better language server that VSCode uses to IntelliJ Idea (via a plugin or stricter settings maybe?) and tell the Java compiler to report and reject all these issues?

Here are some exemplary issues:

```
Redundant superinterface <bla> for the type <foo>, already defined by <foobar> Java(16777547)

The import <foo> is never used Java(268435844)

The method <foo> from the type <bar> is deprecated Java (67108967)

<Foo> is a raw type. References to generic type <Foo<bar>> should be parameterized. Java(16777788)
```

Comment: I suspect that a few of those messages are visible in a clean IntelliJ installation too.

Comment: I use a clean IntelliJ installation.

Comment: And no *Settings Repository* set? Under File - Manage IDE Settings

Comment: IntelliJ still honors the "intelligent" in its name. Unused imports are gray I believe, and one can clean them up. A SonarLint plugin gives more analysis. The latest IntelliJ version should do more code analysis. Try to not alienate your colleagues and stay in the java realm. It already is really a bad state; code quality should always be a consideration.

Comment: Unless you're the team manager, just clean up the code you are tasked with modifying.

Answer (score -1):

**Extension Pack for Java** uses [Eclipse ™ JDT Language Server](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls) to provide Java ™ language support, and there's no such settings in VS Code to change it to [intellij-lsp](https://github.com/gtache/intellij-lsp).

Clicking the error redirects to the code, use `quick fix` can solve some of your questions.